# Terragrunt and tflint warnings "Variable declared but not used"

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, tflint

I use `Terraform` and `Terragrunt`.

I use `inputs` field in `terragrunt.hcl` file from where I also call a local module:

```
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

terraform {
  source = "../../modules/dns"
}

inputs = {
  dns_zone_id = "1234"
}
```

But it seems that I **also** must declare `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "dns_zone_id" {
  description = "Cloudflare DNS zone ID"
  type        = string
}
```

If I do not declare `variables.tf` file I get errors when running `terragrunt plan`:

```
An input variable with the name "dns_zone_id" has not been
│ declared. This variable can be declared with a variable
│ "dns_zone_id" {} block.
```

But the **problem is** that `tflint` complains and does not understand that variables is used in `inputs` block in `terragrunt.hcl` file:
[image]

Is there any workaround for this issue besides using `tflint ignore`? Am i missing something in `terragrunt`? I do not see in `terragrunt` docs that they use `variables.tf`.
Best regards

Comment: An error in Terragrunt would supersede anything that a third party linter tool would warn/suggest.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard Sure, but am I missing something, I cant see that terragrunt uses variables.tf much with inputs field.